# STM8S Cosmic compiler defines

Tags: c

I am new to the Cosmic compiler and STM8.

In `iostm8s103.h` the Switch control register is defined as 
`volatile char CLK_SWCR      @0x50c5;`

How do I address the switch busy bit (`SWBSY bit 0`) in that register?
I need to wait until the switch busy bit is clear. (While bit)
It is strange that I cannot find an example for the Cosmic compiler.

Comment: Can you get the STM8S C peripheral library?

Comment: Note sure what the `@` does. Can you access it like this: `*(char *)0x50c5 & 0x1`?

Answer (score 0):

With the micro-controller, using volatile registers is simple.

```
#include <iostm8s103.h>

CLK_SWCR |= SWBSY; // to set the bit 0

CLK_SWCR &= ~SWBSY; // to reset the bit 0
```

> In the [iostm8s103.h](https://github.com/wlianmin/stm8_usb/blob/master/FW/toolchain/Hstm8/iostm8s103.h), the register is defined as follow:

```
volatile char CLK_SWCR      @0x50c5;    /* Switch Control reg */
```

So, to wait while BUSY, with that iostm8s103.h, the code looks like:

```
while ((CLK_SWCR | SWBSY) != 0);
```

> If using the [stm8s.h](https://github.com/EarToEarOak/DDS-Sine-Sweep/blob/master/src/stm8s.h) instead of iostm8s103.h, the CLK registers
>   are defined as struct.

So, to wait while BUSY, with that stm8s.h, the code looks like:

```
while ((CLK->SWCR | CLK_SWCR_SWBSY) != 0);
```

or

```
while (CLK->SWCR & CLK_SWCR_SWBSY);
```

Comment: What does the `@` mean? I've never seen that before.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `CLK->SWCR` rather than `CLK_SWCR`?

Comment: the `volatile char CLK_SWCR` is not declared as a struct, you can't use the form `CLK->SWCR`. Maybe the mask of bit 0 corresponding to `SWBSY` should be defined, because not seen in the header.

Comment: Yes, I can get the STM8S peripheral library. The puzzle is that the defines are different to the Cosmic defines.
The @ refers to the address.
Yes, it is CLK_SWCR, not a struct. In the ST library it is called CLK_SWCR_SWBSY.

Comment: Thank you, yes I can get the STM8S peripheral library, but it is different to the Cosmic headers. It is not a struct in Cosmic headers.
The SWBSY name I got from ST publication RM0016.
ST calls it CLK_SWCR_SWBSY.
Strange!
smitjs@vodamail.co.za

Comment: The @ means the address as far as I can see.

Comment: @user3824211 adding the expected source code. I have also seen `while (CLK_SWCR_SWBSY != 0);` with a non-Cosmic header.

Comment: @user3824211 There should be `#ifdef COSMIC` directives in the STM8S library.

Comment: Thank you all.It appears the answer is to use STM8s.h instead of the Cosmic header, because the Cosmic header does not define the bits.
Quite correct, the ST header does have a Cosmic directive.

Comment: @user3824211 adding the use with stm8s.h